# Python equivalence to org.apache.commons.configuration?

Tags: java, python, apache-commons, apache-commons-config

I want to port this `Configuration.class` object (from http://pastebin.com/dZeV27XB) into python and it seems hard to port the org.apache.commons.configuration object

In the java class, there were multiple functions that returns a `Configuration.getString` or `Configuration.getInt` e.g.

```
  public int getDumpEndDir()
  {
    return this.config.getInt("wiki.dump.endDir");
  }

  public String getDocDir()
  {
    return this.config.getString("wiki.dump.docDir");
  }
```

**Any clue to what such function return?**

**Is there a python library similar to `org.apache.commons`?**
Especially if there is one with the `org.apache.commons.configuration` library.

**Is there a reason why this is in Java but not python?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's inbuild ConfigParser module which is very similar to Java's properties file loader. But here, the configuration parameters will be split section-wise.
check this,
https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

If it is an inmemory config structure, then you can simply use a dictionary object...